# Rails Conditional Query over Join Table

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a join table connecting Items to Tags with a many-to-many relation.  I'm trying to do a paginated view of all the items where if a search is made all items where the name or the tag name matches will be included.

When I do:

```
    search = "one"
    Item.all(:conditions=>["items.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"]);
```

I get on resulting item which contains the word "one" in it.

Then when I do:

```
    search = "one"
    Item.all(:joins=>[:tags], :conditions=>["items.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"]);
```

I get an empty set.

Why is active record giving me an empty set instead of still giving me the one result which matches the conditions?  And how might I get the results Im looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Turns out `:joins=>[:tags]` does by default an `INNER JOIN` when what is needed by my query is an `OUTER JOIN`.  The solution to my problem is to do

```
    search = "one"
    Item.all(
        :joins=>['LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags_items" ON "tags_items"."webservice_id" = "webservices"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "tags_items"."tag_id"'], 
        :conditions=>["items.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"]
    )
```